# Using OData substringof with Linked Model Property

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api, odata

Using the odata substringof method like so:

```
filter=substringof('" + $("#txtSearch").val() + "',Postcode) eq true
```

Which is ok, but if I want to search against a linked property like so:

```
filter=substringof('" + $("#txtSearch").val() + "',Client.Name) eq true
```

It returns results but the filter wasn't applied. I basically have a Job and Client model whereby I want to search the jobs by client name via WebApi.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can filter only for properties which are expanded. In you case you should do:

```
$filter=substringof('" + $("#txtSearch").val() + "', Client/Name)&$expand=Client
```

Good luck!

Comment: ASP .Net returned expand as not supported but adding the slash instead of the fullstop got this working, thanks.